# Reversing the first two columns of a DataFrame and appending results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that looks similar to the following:

```
value1 value2 value3 
A      B       1
C      D       2
E      F       3
```

I want to create a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
value1 value2 value3 
A      B       1
C      D       2
E      F       3
B      A       1
D      C       2
F      E       3
```

In other words, I want to switch around `value1` and `value2` while retaining the same `value3`, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Seems trivial - have you tried it? you can use slicing to reverse the rows like this `.iloc[::-1, :-1]`. You'll also find [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) useful. Please post an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value1':['A','C','E'],'value2':['B','D','F'],'value3':[1,2,3]})
df2 = df.append(df.rename(columns={'value1':'value2','value2':'value1'}), sort=False)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  value1 value2  value3
0      A      B       1
1      C      D       2
2      E      F       3
0      B      A       1
1      D      C       2
2      F      E       3
```